# How come when I write <a href> hyper links for my website to compile and run in mozilla firefox even though it works in other compilers?

Tags: html, firefox, hyperlink

I was programming a website with HTML 5 and running it in firefox, but when I write Example the hyperlink text doesn't appear on the website. However, when I run it in another compiler it appears just fine. Should I start using another compiler or is there a simple solution to this problem?

I've tried to search for a simple solution since this is just a basic website that I am going to be using for sort of data base for my high school portfolio(for the other programming projects I've done in java and C#),however I haven't found a clear solution(since I don't know much more than the basics of HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First Website</title>
    </head>
    <body style = "background-color:beige;">
        <nav style = "text-align:center;">
        <a href = "./index.html">Homepage</a>
        <br>
        <a href = "./JavaPortfolio.html">Programs I wrote in Java</a>
        <br>
        <a href = "./CSharpPortfolio.html">Programs I wrote in C Sharp</a>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
<!--Not all of my code but you get the idea-->
```

I expected the hyperlink word to appear on screen, but the actual output in a blank spot where the text should've been. :(

Comment: I cant tell what the problem is. This links appear on all browsers I use just fine (edge, ff, chrome).

Comment: Thanks it seems the problem was with the rest of my code. Sorry for being such a html newb